# Adjust of the fseek for read number

Tags: c, scanf, fseek

I can't get the right numbers from the following text file. I only can get from early lines of the file. I'm using the *fseek* function, but itsn't working. I wanna be able to get the number in position 1024 for example. My file has 32 float numbers in sequence.

```
#DEFINE N 1026 //The number that I want read
#DEFINE SIZEFLOAT 9 //-1.849728 Nine digits
float data
fseek(arq, (((N-1) * SIZEFLOAT) + ( N / 31.0 ) ) * sizeof(char), SEEK_SET);
fscanf(arq, "%f", &data);
```

Here is how my data file looks:

```
-1.849728+3.491089+2.169375-5.024082-4.683389-1.621853-3.976242+4.346661-2.634182-0.647340-4.725379+4.996003+0.965050+1.515107-4.365746+4.977995-2.800827+1.541677-1.292648-1.701067-0.883889-0.081253+3.928178+2.617783-2.590111+2.277843+0.856840+1.676386-4.604098-1.937928-2.174185-1.333826
-3.566839+5.115190-1.237908-3.130227-1.626663-0.094150-3.903567+0.859154+4.378510-3.508946+0.735157+0.223560+3.126161+1.489411+0.081555-4.794665-2.088912+3.908907-1.375732+2.147199-1.292346-2.567554-0.355018+1.237543+4.830288-4.618177-2.206071-4.893809-1.436105+0.739744-1.107636+0.117056
... More rows of data similar to the above...
```

The complete file can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/M9aTk0zD).

Comment: Pastebin links are not acceptable here, either put the code in the question, of if it's too long, make a SSCCE.

Comment: @sashoalm It's not code in pastebin, it's a pretty boring data file. I edited to include a representative part of it, and kept the boring part in pastebin.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the logic in the calculation for fseek?  What does ( N / 31.0 ) mean? why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My file has 32 float numbers in sequence.

More specifically, your *text* file has rows of 32 float numbers formatted as text to nine positions; each row has an end-of-line character at the end.

With this information in hand, you can compute the offset of the `k`-th number by first dividing it by 32 to obtain the row, then multiplying row number by the size of a single row, and adding the offset within the current line, like this:

```
#define NUM_SIZE 9
#define ROW_NUM_COUNT 32
#define ROW_SIZE (ROW_NUM_COUNT*NUM_SIZE+1)
...
int k = 123; // The index of the number that you need to read
int offset = ROW_SIZE(k / ROW_NUM_COUNT) * ROW_SIZE + NUM_SIZE * (k % ROW_NUM_COUNT);
...
float data;
fseek(arq, offset);
fscanf(arq, "%f", &data);
```